# The executable is absent yet I can execute the command on the command line

Tags: windows, command-line

There's such utility for Windows developers called `regtlib`. I have three computers - one with WinXP, another two with Win2k3. If I run built-in Windows search for file with wildcard `regtlib*` on the whole filesystem search finds nothing on all three computers.

If I try to execute `regtlib` on WinXP command line it says it can't find such a file or built-in command. The same on one of the two Win2k3 computers. But when I do that on the other Win2k3 computer I see typical `regtlib` output.

What happens? What is the magic that invokes `regtlib` without the file being present on the filesystem?

Comment: Are you searching hidden folers/files?

Comment: @user26453: Actually, no. and that was the problem. Once I ticked "more options" and then "search system and hidden" it got found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are searching hidden folders/files.

Comment: Actually that's what it was. Sounds naive, but I never really expected that search would by default skip hidden and system files.

Answer (score 3):

`regtlib` does have to be present on the file-system.  There are a couple of things you can do to find it.  First, if it is not in the current directory it has to be in one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.  You can see the directories using this command:

```
echo %PATH%
```

If that doesn't help you could use Sysinternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to help you track down the path to the executable that is running.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
for %x in (regtlib.exe) do @echo.%~dp$PATH:x
```

which should show you the place where the program resides.

Answer (score 0):

It could be coming from a Windows cache.

Comment: What cache? And why would it be added to %PATH%?